# Initialize deliver class by base class on Parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have some Class like this:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public void MethodOfBase(){}
}
public class Deliver1 : BaseClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Deliver2 : BaseClass
{
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
}
public class Deliver3 : BaseClass
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

I have some code:

```
    public void Method1()
    {
        Deliver1 deliver1 = null;
        MethodWithBaseClass(deliver1);

        Deliver2 deliver2 = null;
        MethodWithBaseClass(deliver2);

        Deliver3 deliver3 = new Deliver3();
        MethodWithBaseClass(deliver3);


    }

    public void MethodWithBaseClass(BaseClass baseClass)
    {
        if(baseClass == null)
            baseClass = ???
    }
```

I want to initialize the deliver
But i don't want to check like this:

```
    public void MethodWithBaseClass(BaseClass baseClass)
    {
        if (baseClass == null && baseClass is Deliver1)
            baseClass = new Deliver1();
        else if.....
    }
```

Because it's too much IF check.
Is it possible? And how do to that?

Thank you so much!

Comment: "I want to initialize the deliver" Be carefull: **initializing** assumes you already **have an instance created**, which you do. You can pass that instance into your method and **modify its properties or fields**. What you seem to want instead is to **pass the type** to tghe method and let that method **create a new instance** of that type. You´re mixing both: you **create** an instance in order to get its type and **create a new one**.

Comment: a factory pattern might be nice here...

Comment: Okay. I remove that. Sorry :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible with the code you've written, since `if (baseClass == null && baseClass is Deliver1)` will always return `false`. That is because checking the type on a `null` reference doesn't work (it checks the value, not the backing variable type).

You have to use generics (and `ref`) in this case, but I don't think it is a particular good design:

```
public void MethodWithBaseClass<T>(ref T instance) where T : new()
{
    if (instance == null)
    {
        instance = new T();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Deliver1 deliver1 = null;
MethodWithBaseClass(ref deliver1);
```

Comment: ... or `out`, which is somewhat better than `ref` in this context.

Comment: There can already be an instance, as in example 3. You would need an in and out argument then. @ZoharPeled

Comment: Thank you! I have just been enlightened! :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you´re just usng the passed instance to get its type and create a new instance of that type. This seems odd to me.

Aside from that you´re mixing two things: **initializing** assumes you already **have an instance created**, as in your current code. You can pass that instance into your method and **modify** its properties or fields, but you can´t change that instance (unless you´d use `ref`-keyword). What you seem to want instead is to pass the **type** to the method and let that method create a new instance of that type.

```
public BaseClass MethodWithBaseClass(Type baseClass)
{
    return (BaseClass) Activator.CreateInstance(baseClass);
}
```

Now call it like this:

```
var newInstance = MethodWithBaseClass(typeof(Derived1));
```

This will of course throw a `InvalidCastException` if you provide a type that does not inherit from `BaseClass`. This means you lose the strong typing, meaning you don´t know at **compile**-time the exact type you get from the method. You can also make the method generic:

```
public T MethodWithBaseClass<T>() where T: BaseClass, new()
{
    return new T();
}
```

and call it like this:

```
var newInstance = MethodWithBaseClass<Derived1>();
```

This enables strong typing, but assumes you know the exact type at compile-time.

Comment: I prefer the type safety of generics.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I agree, however it feels cumbersome to provide an instance for the sake of getting its type.

Comment: OP is not passing the instance just to get the type. It seems it already can be instantiated.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Well, he overrites that instance, which would only make sense if he´d use the ref-keyword. Furthermore he declares them explicitely as `Delviered1 d = null`, which makes me feel he´s abusing that instance to get its type.

Comment: Only if it hasn't been instantiated yet.

Comment: `public T MethodWithBaseClass<T>() => Activator.CreateInstance<T>();` - no need to pass instance